# Cannot get the missing elements when comparing two different csv columns using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two csv files
The first has about 420 values in rows in one column
The second has about 203 rows with 6 columns

File 1

```
x1
x2
x3

...
```

File 2

```
x1;a1;b1;c1;d1;e1
x2;a1;b1;c1;d1;e1
x3;a1;b1;c1;d1;e1
x5;a1;b1;c1;d1;e1
x6;a1;b1;c1;d1;e1
```

I try with the following way to put them into two different lists

```
skuslist =[]
retaillist =[]

def myskus():
    contents = []
    with open('SKUS.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8',newline='') as csvf:
        reader = csv.reader(csvf, delimiter=";")
        for row in reader:
            contents.append(row)  # Add each sku to list contents
    return contents

def myretails():
    retails = []
    with open('retails_csv.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8',newline='') as csvf:
        reader = csv.reader(csvf, delimiter=";")
        for row in reader:
            retails.append(row[0])
    return retails

skuslist = myskus()
retaillist = myretails()
```

**and export the elements in SKU list which are not in retaillist**

```
with open('export.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\n')
    for item in skuslist:
        if item not in retaillist:
            writer.writerow(item)
```

Instead of getting the missing elements I get ALL the elements of SKU list 420 count

I should waiting for elements

```
x4
x7
..
```

Elements that are missing from retail list
Shouldn't I wait for 217 elements ?
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`csv.reader` yields a list of items, so when you do:

```
for row in reader:
    contents.append(row)  # Add each sku to list contents
```

it adds a list, rather than a string, to the `contents` list, for every iteration of the loop, so when you:

```
for item in skuslist:
```

`item` becomes a list of one item, rather than a string.

Change it to:

```
for sku, in reader:
    contents.append(sku)
```

so that the SKU is unpacked from the list that the CSV reader generates.

Also note that you should pass a list of items to `writer.writerow`; otherwise the string you pass to it would be treated as an iterable and you would see a single character on each line:

```
writer = csv.writer(f)
for item in skuslist:
    if item not in retaillist:
        writer.writerow([item])
```

Comment: Even so item or [item] I get the whole initial list and not the ones that missing

Comment: Because each item in `skulist` is now a list, which cannot be equal to the items in `retaillist`, which are strings, so `if item not in retaillist:` always evaluates to `True`.

Comment: How can I fix it to get the missing elements?

Comment: I already showed you how to fix it in my answer. Please read it and try it. Both the "Change it to:" part and the bottom part.

Comment: I tried it :) but I get ['x1'] ['x2'] etc in each row total 420 count

Comment: No, make sure you include the comma in `for sku, in reader:` as I showed you above, as it is crucial to unpacking each row as a list.

Comment: 1 , makes a difference It seems that is working!!! but if I have initialy 420 and the second list has 203 shouldnt I expect 217 and not 273???  What could be these extra 56? ???